# Automated nested objects

Tags: javascript, nested-loops, javascript-objects

A couple of days ago I was having fun with some js, when I came to the question if I could automate object nesting. Of course I'm still a newby so I haven't gotten too far.

But what I got is this:

```
var a = {};
var stso = ""; storing the second object

function sto(b) { // start the object
    a[b] = {};
    stso = b;
}

function nmo(...objs) { // nesting more object
    console.log(objs[0]);
    if(objs.length) { // checking to see that I have at least one variable before proceding
        for(i = 0; i < objs.length; i++) { // looping through arguments
            a[stso][objs[i]] = {}; // and now I would have to repeat one more more for lever for every argument, meaning, the deeper I want to go into the object, the more nested for loops I have to make.
        }
    }
}

sto("b");
nmo("c");
a.b.c = "Happy ending!";

console.log(a.b.c); // It seems we still dont have a happy ending

// and as a second example

sto("b");
nmo("c", "d", "e", "f", "g");
a.b.c.d.e.f.g = "Another happy ending!";

console.log(a.b.c.d.e.f.g); // Our second happy ending was also unhappy...
```

In summary, you define the second object in one function, you define as many objects as you want in your second function in order.

How could I achieve this with my current structure?

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: It's too hard to tell exactly what you're asking.  Please show a before and after data structure that shows your desired input and output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understand you correctly, you can do something like this:

```
var createNestedObjects = function( obj ) {
    //get all the passed arguments 
    var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);

    //start with i = 1, as we want to skip obj in the arguments
    for( var i = 1; i < args.length; i++ ) {
        obj = obj[ args[i] ] = obj[ args[i] ] || {};
    }

};

var a = {};
createNestedObjects( a, "b", "c", "d", "e", "f" );
a.b.c.d.e.f = "happy ending";
console.log(a.b.c.d.e.f); //logs "happy ending"
```

---

**explanation line 3**

Your requirement is to pass as many strings as required to the function to create any size of nested objects you would like. 
However, as you can see, the function only has one parameter: obj.
The cool thing is that javascript allows you to pass even more parameters and you are still able to access them using the arguments object. The arguments object is available in all functions. The arguments object is similar to an array, but not quite the same as it is an object in it's own, if you log it in this case it will display:

```
Arguments [{}, "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"] (6)
```

We can't loop through the agruments object using a for loop, so on line 3 it's converted to an array first.
[arguments object reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments)

---

**explanation inside the loop**

There are two interesting parts in this line. Javascript allows you to assign multiple variables at once as the assignment operator assigns a value to its left operand based on the value of its right operand

```
  var a, b;
  a =  b = 10; //both a and b are set to 10
```

Using || operator is used here to set a default value ( in this case {} )if the value on the left is undefined. Which is for example also handy to set default values

```
function setDelay ( delay ){

    delay = delay || 60
    return delay

}

setDelay(  ) //no parameter is passed, delay is set to 60 
setDelay( 120 ) 120 is passed and delay is set to 120
```

In this case the line

```
obj = obj[ args[i] ] = obj[ args[i] ] || {};
```

can be rewritten as:

```
var name = args[i];    // first loop args[i] is "b"    
if(!obj[name]){        // a.b does not exist       
    obj[name] = {};    // a.b is set to {}      
}
obj = obj[name];       // a is set to a.b
```

which checks if there is already an object with that name, if not it's created and set as obj so we can nest objects in the next loop.

I hope this clarifies the code

Comment: I like how you followed the overall structure I gave, but I am not completely understanding what is happening in line three, and inside of the loop, could you further explain?

Comment: Thank you, now I understand what is happening. Great explanation!

Answer (score 1):

So, you want to convert values to a nested object? This can be done by doing something like this:

```js
let values = ['b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g'];
let a = {};
// Every time we loop, we change the root
let root = a;

for (let value of values) {
  // Set root to the value of the array and assign a new object
  root = root[value] = {};
}
// Set the string
a.b.c.d.e.f.g = "Happy ending!";

console.log(a.b.c.d.e.f.g);
console.log(a);
```

It basically does this inside the loop:

```
a = a[b] = {};
a[b] = a[b][c] = {};
a[b][c] = a[b][c][d] = {};
a[b][c][d] = a[b][c][d][e] = {};
a[b][c][d][e] = a[b][c][d][e][f] = {};
a[b][c][d][e][f] = a[b][c][d][e][f][g] = {};
```

It creates a new key every loop and assigns an empty object to it. The next iteration creates a new key (with an empty object as value) inside the newly created object from the previous loop. This goes on until all values of the array have been assigned.

Comment: This is a very creative way to answer my question. However, when you explain what happens inside the loop you say that `a[b] = a[b][c]` and `{}`. How is that possible?

Comment: The first part before the first `=` is the value of root. The root variable then creates a new key (in this case `c`) inside the `a[b]` so root becomes `a[b][c]`. After the last `=` you can see it creates a new empty object to `a[b][c]` so that the next iteration can do this all over again but then with `d`.